# How do I get date time stamp of a file since last it was modified in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I have requirement to **read the last modified time of a log file** in the Magento 2  like `Apr 10, 2017, 6:47:17 AM`

The log file will be present under `var/log` directory of Magento. How can implement it? Is there a method in core Magento for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created one module to search and get the modified files. you can get list from command line.

This Magento 2 Module is use to search string and find modified files in Magento Root Directory.

It is very easy to search content, search content in specific directory.

Also you can search the modified files within the folder.

Please refer the URL: https://github.com/ashish-wagento/module-searchmodified

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DirectorIterator` class to do so.

I'm not sure exactly how you want to achieve that but here's a small script that can be used to do what you want:

```
$modificationsTimes = array();
foreach (new DirectorIterator("/path/to/var/log/directory") as $file) {
    if (!$file->isDir() && file_exists($file->getPathname())) {
        $modificationTimes[$file->getFilename()] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $file->getMTime());
    }
}
```

The `$modificationTimes` array will contain an association of entries where the key is the log file name and the value is the last modification time of the file.

NB: this code is pure PHP it does not use any core Magento methods / classes.

Comment: I have requirement to show this time in a Admin Grid column.

Comment: I was using the function getMtime.. I am getting an error `splfileInfo` getMtime() stat failed